docker postgres: how to use password from a secrets.yml file
I am trying to put all of an app's secrets into a single file. Previously, each secret had its own file, like this:
.secrets/
├── .allowedhosts
├── .key
└── .passwd

Accordingly, the docker-compose.yaml looked like this:
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:15-alpine
    environment:
      ...
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/db_password
    secrets:
      - db_password

secrets:
  db_password:
    file: .secrets/.passwd

This worked great.
But how do I achieve something similar when the password is stored in a yaml file? For example .secrets.yml:
ALLOWED_HOSTS: localhost,127.0.0.1
DATABASE_PASSWORD: supersecret
SECRET_KEY: ohnomysecretkeyisleaking

As far as I am aware, the postgres image expects the password secret to be plainly stored in a simple file - not in a yaml.
Currently I just create a separate .passwd file that contains the same password from the secrets file, but this feels clumsy (two places where the password is stored) and prone to divergence should the password be changed.
The password file is only relevant when the container is created, so is there maybe a docker compose hook I could use to generate the password file before building a container?
Or is there a simpler, more elegant way that I am just not seeing?

If you want to store secrets in YAML files, you will need to add logic somewhere (e.g., an init container) to extract secrets from the YAML files and populate plain files on disk, since this is what Postgres expects. Alternately, instead of secrets, store everything in a .env file and expose them as environment variables (there is a different risk model here, but it may not matter for your use case).

Thanks, that init container idea looks helpful.
